# animate one sibling at a time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm having problem with some jquery code. So the story is, I'm trying to write a snake game using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
initial_move();
$(document).keydown(function(e){
         switch (e.keyCode) { 
        case 38:
            $('#snake-body').stop().add('#one').animate({marginTop:'-2%'},'fast');
            return('null');
        case 37: 
            return('null');
        case 39:
            return('null');
        case 40: 
            alert('bottom');
            return('null');
          }
      });
});
function initial_move(){
  $('#snake-body').css('margin-left','0%');
  $('#snake-body').animate({marginLeft:'100%'},5000,'linear',initial_move);
}

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="snake-body">
   <div id="2" class="part"></div>
       <div id="1" class="part"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm stuck while trying to make the snake parts move according to keydown. when i press the up arrow key, first the div with `id="one"` should move up and followed by `id="two"` and so on.

But this code moves both the div simultaneously to `margintop:'-2%'`. I don't understand because I've targeted only the `id="one"` div in the code..

```
   case 38:
   $('#snake-body').stop().add('#one').animate({marginTop:'-2%'},'fast');
```

I hope someone could help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you write ``[..].add('#one') [...]`` but then it is ``id="1"``?

Comment: its semantically bad to use numbers for ids. always start with an alphabet. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @mzedeler, oh sorry..it actually is id="one"

Comment: It would be much easier to help if we had a description, in words, of how the animation is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$('#snake-body').stop().add('#one').animate({marginTop:'-2%'},'fast');
```

Is the same as this code:

```
$('#snake-body').stop();
$('#snake-body, #one').animate({marginTop:'-2%'},'fast');
```

Which means you're updating both the `#snake-body`, and the `#one` part.

This is because `add()` adds the `#one` div to what you've already selected... meaning you've got both the parent (#snake-body) and the part (#one) selected at the same time.

What you probably want to do instead is this:

```
$('#snake-body').stop();
$('#one').animate({marginTop:'-2%'},'fast');
```

Depending on what you're intending the `.stop()` for, you may want to stop the individual parts instead of the parent:

```
$('#snake-body .part').stop();
$('#one').animate({marginTop:'-2%'},'fast');
```